# src/app/components/home/home.component.ts:17:14 - error TS2339: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'

Tags: angular, typescript, api, http, angular-cli

I am new into the field, learning every day from you, today I have this problem but I have been reading other post but I can not understand what is going on.
I will show you my service and home component.

I am trying to print this data.
https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/random.php

Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
//Get Data from API
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
//MAP Array OF OBJECTS
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  //Providing this service into app.MODULE
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CocktailService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

    console.log('Cocktail SERVICE READY')

  }

  getRandomCocktail() {
    this.http.get('https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/random.php')
        .pipe(map ( data => {
          return data['drinks'].srtDrink;
        }));
        // .subscribe( resp => {
        //   console.log(resp);
        // })
  }
}
```

Home component (subscribe problem, here)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CocktailService } from '../../services/cocktail.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent {

  cocktailData: any[] = [];
  constructor( private http: HttpClient,
                private cocktail: CocktailService ) {

        this.cocktail.getRandomCocktail()
        .subscribe( (data: any) => {
          this.cocktailData = data
          return this.http.get('https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/random.php');
        });
   }
}
```

I will really appreciate your help to understand what is happening in here with the .subscribe
Do I need to subscribe from the component?  I am getting the data into the service, I am lost.
I am following a tutorial but I am using a different  API.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `getRandomCocktail()` isn't returning the request. Add a `return`: `return this.http.get(...`. Also please post code as snippets instead of screenshots. It makes hard to reproduce the error.

Comment: Your getRandomCocktail isn't returning anything... Stick a "return" in front of "this.http.get.('..." . You also need a return type Observable<T>. Also to help debug get rid of your pipe on your service (put it back when you have it going). Just have service make the http call and return that result as a specified type. If you don't know the return type, used Observable<any>. Best of luck